# BG1 on top of BG2 with opacity?

Tags: html, css

I am currently learning to code, and I have gotten really far thanks to this website. However, I am stuck on a problem for my website, and I cannot seem to figure out how to get this to work properly.

I have found several answers to my questions, but the images don't show, or lowering the opacity triggers the whole page.

What I need help with is; how could I make BG1 as a background, and have BG2 on top of BG1, with both of them being behind my Tables and table rows, and such?

What I'm trying to achieve: [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUhhM.jpg) | [example 2](http://puu.sh/pgeCk/d4206f6388.jpg)

Comment: Can you include example code in your post?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/joshcrowe/esknedju/1/

```
#container {
  background-image: url(image1.png);
  opacity: 0.7;
}


#container::after {
  content: "";
  background: url(front.png);
  opacity: 0.5;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
```

Having `::after` allows an image to appear over the background image of the element in between `::before` and `::after`.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you. However, it overlaps my Tables. EDIT: I got it working with z-index, but I am unable to move the bg on top of the first bg?

Comment: Would you be as kind as to link me to the code on Pastebin, JSFiddle, Codepen, wherever;  so I can take a look at it?

Comment: I didn't know about the ::after and ::before things :P

Comment: I see. Well 'grats!